# Adding Variable as Plotly Graph Title Error

Tags: python, plotly-python

I'm starting to learn Python and I'm currently using the Plotly Library. For some reason the formatting of my title is causing an error

```
title_font = dict(
                title="<b>Plot</b>",
                size=14,
                color='black',
                family='Arial')

layout = go.Layout(title_font,
                        xaxis= {'title':'Temperature level'},
                        yaxis=dict(title='Sea Level'),
                        hovermode='closest')
```

The error started when I pulled the Title name out of layout and created a variable for it.

Comment: Is this the code that produces the error? What's the traceback?

Comment: @Reti43, ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'size'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `size` property for `layout`, but it's not a valid property for `layout` as the error message says. You had also added the `title` in the `title.font` section which is incorrect. The correct code is:

```
title_font = dict(
                size=14,
                color='black',
                family='Arial')

layout = go.Layout(title="<b>Plot</b>",
                   title_font=title_font,
                        xaxis= {'title':'Temperature level'},
                        yaxis=dict(title='Sea Level'),
                        hovermode='closest')
```